# Favicon appended at the end of URL

Tags: html, web, nginx

Nginx logs of my site hav multiple 404 entries with:

```
GET /entryfavicon.ico HTTP/1.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/ie-tab-l/indexIE.html
```

A right URL would be GET /entry, but for some weird reason favicon is appended at the end.

Looking at the HTML source, the favicon has an absolute path:

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
    location = /entryfavicon.ico {
            access_log      off;
            return          204;
    }
```